# Setting a custom position for UINavigationController

Tags: uinavigationcontroller

In my iPad app I'd like to place a small UINavigationController inside my main view. By default the navController sizes to full screen, so I adjusted its frame as follows:

```
[self.navController.view setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 400)];
[self.navController.view setFrame:CGRectMake(500, 200, 320, 400)];
```

This works visually, ie. the controller ends up in the right position with the right frame size. However, its "hot area" seems to remain at (0,0), meaning I can't interact with it outside the bounds rectangle. So if I place it at (50,100), part of the control still receives interaction events. But if I set my x and y values beyond 320 and 400, no touches go through.

Is there any solution to this? Or is it simply a bad idea trying to do this with UINavigationController?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

False alarm! It was a total oversight on my part. I was actually attaching to the wrong view than one I thought. Palm to face.